# How to access the location other than wwwroot in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can access the physical location of a server using `Server.MapPath`. This gives me the physical path that is inside of `wwwroot` folder.

I want to Save some data into the other drive of the same server say `D:` drive. I think I can't get the physical location of `D:` drive using `Server.MapPath` because it is outside of the `wwwroot` folder. So I will hardcoded this location into my project. But now the problem is I want to access the saved data using server url like `www.mysite.com/image/myimage.png`
where `image/myimage.png` located in `D:` drive. So I just want to know is it possible or not using asp.net or please suggest what should i do to overcome this problem

Comment: Create a virtual directory under IIS and point that to your D drive location.

Comment: My guess, since I have never done this, is that if you have to specify where to save it, then you will need to specify where to retrieve it as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, a couple things:

- Don't hardcode your location, use appsettings in your web.config, that's what they are there for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- You want to serve images from another drive. You need to set up a virtual directory in IIS under your website to achieve this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible or then it would be possible for any one to make script to upload files to any folder he wants. If you have access to the server consider making application to move your files.